# How do I include multiple tables while using ||$cont|| in my url query parameter using the '&or' condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, vue.js

**html:**

```
<v-col cols="2">
    <v-text-field label="Staff" :disabled="disabled" v-model="search" />
</v-col>
<v-col cols="2" class="d-flex justify-end footer-btn-container">
    <v-btn
        :disabled="disabled"
        color="success"
        @click="fetchManagers()">
        Search
    </v-btn>
</v-col>
```

**javascript:**

```
async fetchManagers () {
  let param = `filter=staffId2||$cont||${this.search}&or=firstName||$cont||${this.search}`
  await this.fetchEmployee({ pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 1000000, param: param })
}

const actions = {
  async fetchEmployee ({ commit }, { pageNumber, pageSize, param }) {
    try {
      const response = await getAllEmployee(pageNumber, pageSize, param)
      commit('setEmployee', response.data)
    } catch (error) {
    // handle the error here
    }
  }


import httpClient from './httpClient'

const END_POINT = '/staff'

const getAllEmployee = (pageNumber, pageSize, param) => httpClient.get(`${END_POINT}?${param}`, { params: { 'page': pageNumber, 'limit': pageSize } })
```

The above works but when I try for multiple fields, it doesn't give the proper result

```
let param = `filter=staffId2||$cont||${this.search}&or=firstName||$cont||${this.search}&or=lastName||$cont||${this.search}&or=middleName||$cont||${this.search}&or=branch||$cont||${this.search}`
  await this.fetchEmployee({ pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 1000000, param: param })
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome, i suggest to update the question including some more details because from just the code you posted there is no way to figure out what is going wrong. For example how did you implemented the method "fetchEmployee"? how does it processes the parameter "param"? what are you sending to the server in the request and what the server is expecting to receive? what is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved it. all I had to do was remove `filter` and put `where`

From this

```
filter=staffId2||$cont||${this.search}&or=firstName||$cont||${this.search}
 &or=lastName||$cont||${this.search}&or=middleName||$cont||${this.search}
 &or=branch||$cont||${this.search}
```

To this

```
where&or=staffId2||$cont||${this.search}&or=branch.name||$cont||${this.search}
 &or=surname||$cont||${this.search}&or=firstName||$cont||${this.search}"
```